# problems implementing FragmentTabHost.setup

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

i get this error in eclipse while implementing FragmentTabHost

**The method setup(Context, FragmentManager, int) in the type FragmentTabHost is not applicable for the arguments (Context, FragmentManager, int)**

been following the official android post and refereed to a couple of other sites too,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

any suggestions ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're extending `FragmentActivity` and using classes from compatibility package. When calling setup, you're probably calling it like this:

```
setup(this, getFragmentManager(), containerId);
```

Call it like this:

```
setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), containerId);
```

This answer is based on assumptions - since you didn't provide more details about how you're calling setup and what are your parent classes.

Comment: hey thanx mans !! i wated about three days looking in for finding a solution !!

Comment: @gunar, I am not using FragmentActivity, minsdk=14, I am adding fragemnt with navigation drawer,
now I want to add tabs within an individual fragment, added fragmentTabHost in my layout, but having same error in onCreateView of Fragment Class,
I have added updated v13 support lib for navigation drawer, so FragmentTabHost is also deriving from it,,,,